# Multiple NIntegrate (again)

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

Basically I have the same question as here:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37146/multiple-nintegrate
but since I don't have enough "reputation" I cannot comment there.

I want to solve the following multiple Integral numerically at given Points R, m:

```
Qb[R_, m_] := 3/m^2 + 8/(Sqrt[Pi] m)
NIntegrate[Exp[-c^2] (-4 m^2/(R Sqrt[Pi]) Integrate[
Exp[-x^2] x^2, {x, 0, Infinity}] - 2 m^2/(R Sqrt[Pi])
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] x^2 Integrate[If[R < Sqrt[c^2 + x^2 - 2 c x z], 
R/Sqrt[c^2 + x^2 - 2 c x z], 1], {z, -1, 1}], {x, 0, Infinity}])
(3 c^2 - 2 c^4), {c, 0, Infinity}]
```

But I get error messages:
*NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand (3\ c^2-2\ c^4)\ E^-c^2\ (-44.7156-50.4562\ !(*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (0), ([Infinity])](*SuperscriptBox[(E), (-Power[<<2>>])]\\ *SuperscriptBox[(x), (2)]\\ (*SubsuperscriptBox[([Integral]), (-1), (1)]If[Less[<<2>>], Times[<<2>>], 1] [DifferentialD]z) [DifferentialD]x))) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{[Infinity],0.}}."*

What is the right way to do this with Mathematica?

Edit:

To make the problem slightly simpler you can leave out all constants and get rid of the x-integration:

```
Qb[R_] := 
NIntegrate[
Exp[-c^2] NIntegrate[
If[R < Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], R/Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], 1], {z, -1, 1}],
{c, 0, Infinity}];
Qb[3.7]
```

or as an even simpler example

```
NIntegrate[NIntegrate[y, {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}]
```

In **this** case it works to replace the inner NIntegrate by Integrate, but if the inner integral is too complicated for analytic evaluation Mathematica cannot handle it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot comment there"? What is the definition of `Qb` used for? Does `R` have a value at some point?  Lots of questions, you could try to debug your code and identify the problematic bits first.

Comment: I cannot comment the other question because it says "you must have 50 reputation".

I just want to insert random values. To check calculations. So say I want to have Qb[3.7,2.8] for example.

It's more a general question, what is the right way to numerically evaluate nested integrations?

Comment: Could you come up with a *simple* example to show what your problem is? Your description and the code are not very clear.

Comment: The trouble is certainly that the Analyic integrals in the integrand are not being exaluated.  The integrand of the "x" intgral depends piecewise on x through the `If`.  Do you perhaps mean for all those integrals to be numeric?

Comment: Yes of course, all integrals should be evaluated numerically. But changing all Integrate to NIntegrate doesn't help. For a simpler example see the edit in my question.

Comment: You need to insert `?NumericQ` tests. For instance, you could do this: `Qb[(R_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Qb2[R, c], {c, 0, Infinity}]; Qb2[(R_)?NumericQ, (c_)?NumericQ] := Exp[-c^2] NIntegrate[If[R < Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], R/Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], 1], {z, -1, 1}]; Qb[3.7]` which gives `1.13579`.

Comment: You should have posted the `simple` example in the first place, and really its ok to edit the question and delete the complicated mess and just ask the specific relatively simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the simplest problem. You ask for `NIntegrate[NIntegrate[y, {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}]`. This doesn't work because when the internal integral is being evaluated, `y` doesn't have any values (hence the error). A simple way to fix this is to do the double integral rather than trying to do two single integrals. Hence:

```
NIntegrate[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
0.5
```

Your next example can be fixed the same way:

```
Qb[R_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-c^2] If[R < Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], R/Sqrt[c^2 - 2 c z], 1], 
              {z, -1, 1}, {c, 0, Infinity}];
Qb[3.7]
1.13579
```